# Matlab gradient

Tags: matlab, gradient

In matlab, I must compute the symbolic gradient of a function f(x) with x a vector of dimension 2.

For example :

```
x=sym('x',[1,2])
f =@(x) 2*x(1)+x(2)
gradient(f,x)
```

An error message says:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in sym/subsref (line 805)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);

Error in @(x)2*x(1)+x(2)

Error in sym>funchandle2ref (line 1285)
    S = x(S{:});

Error in sym>tomupad (line 1188)
    x = funchandle2ref(x);

Error in sym (line 177)
                S.s = tomupad(x);

Error in sym/gradient (line 17)
args = privResolveArgs(sym(f));

Note that it's just an example, actually the function is more complicated and the length of the vector is 10.

Do you know where is the error?

Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

Your defining `f` as a normal Matlab function. That is NOT what you should be doing.

To compute the symbolic gradient:

```
x=sym('x',[1,2]);
f = 2*x(1) + x(2);
g = gradient(f)
```

returns the result `[2; 1]`

This question should also be on stackoverflow in Matlab section.

Comment: What is the difference between f=2*x(1)+x(2) and f=@(x) 2*x(1)+x(2) ?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser `f=@(x) 2*x(1) + x(2)` assigns `f` a function handle to a function which takes in an argument `x` and returns the result of 2*x(1) + x(2). `f` is a function handle in the same way that `@sum` is a function handle to the `sum` function. In contrast `y = 2*x(1) + x(2) ` assigns the `y` the value of 2 * x(1) + x(2). If x were `[1; 3]` the result would be `5` but if `x` is of type `syms`, then the result of `2*x(1) + x(2)` is another symbolic expression. If you want to take the symbolic gradient, you want to pass in  a symbolic expression, not a Matlab function.

Comment: You can type `whos` to see the type of each variable in your workspace. You'll see in the case of `f = @(x) 2*x(1)` that `f` is a function handle. If you define `x = 1` then `f = 2*x(1)` is of type double. And if you do `syms x real;` then `f = 2*x(1)` would be of type `sym`. To take the symbolic gradient, you want to pass `gradient` function a variable of type `sym`.